# CKEditor removing 'i' tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, codemirror

I have [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) content that uses the `i` tag for icons with font-awesome.

```
<div class="service-icon"><i class="icon-exchange"></i></div>
```

[CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) is stripping these tags and the result is:

```
<div class="service-icon">&nbsp;</div>
```

I can't find the right configuration to allow these tags to remain.

I've determined that this is happening because of the [CodeMirror](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codemirror) plugin. If I comment out the CodeMirror plugin, the empty `<i class="icon-exchange"></i>` tags are not removed.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks Dirk, appreciate the link to the answer.

Comment: Actually this answer isn't correct, or isn't fully correct.  It does work to put non-breaking or zero-width spaces, but this isn't really a very elegant solution.  Is there a way to actually configure the editor to ignore specific empty tags, or better yet, simply leave pasted source alone completely?